# Hypotenuse multiplied with multiple numeric values

Tags: javascript

simple numerical code to compute the hypotenuse with the numeric value, i dont know how to decpiher the hypotenuse code in Javascript language" hypo = the square_root of ( sidea squared plus sideb squared)", when i go to my webpage it just shows up blank...what am i missing please inform me on what it was thanks

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Quadratic</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
function Calculate() {
    var a =  document.getElementById("aBox").value;
    var b =  document.getElementById("bBox").value;
    var c = document.getElementById("cBox").value;
    var x = document.getElementById("xBox").value;  
    var y = 0;

    document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML= 'result y = : 'y = ax2 + bx + c;">
}
</head>
<body>
<h2>Quadratic</h2>
<p>
 a: <input type="text" id="aBox" value="2">
<br>
 b: <input type="text" id="bBox" value="3">
<br>
 c: <input type="text" id="cBox" value="4">
 <br>
 x: <input type="text" id="xBox" value="5">
 <br>
 result y = : <input type="text" id="yBox" value="0">
</p>
<div id="outputDiv"> 
<input type="button" value="Calculate quadratic" onclick="Calculate();">
</div>
<hr>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Correct use of JavaScript's [arithmetic operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Arithmetic_operators) and the [`Math.sqrt()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sqrt) will help...

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the script tag in the right place

```
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
```

then your page will at least display

then you need to fix this

```
.innerHTML= 'result y = : 'y = ax2 + bx + c;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/harendra/CpBZu/
This fixes your calculate function to calculate hypotenuse of square. You can do same for other squares as well.

```
function Calculate() {
var a =  parseInt(document.getElementById("aBox").value);
var b =  parseInt(document.getElementById("bBox").value);
var c = parseInt(document.getElementById("cBox").value);
var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("xBox").value);  
var y = Math.sqrt(a*a+a*a);
document.getElementById('yBox').value=y

//document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML= 'result y = : 'y = ax2 + bx + c";
}
```